# Как преобразовать дату в RFC 822 формат в PHP?

Tags: php, rfc

Помогите, пожалуйста. Дата заносится в базу в формате "d.m.Y" (хранится в INT). Как преобразовать ее в формат RFC 822 для RSS? Чтобы было например, 10 августа 2015 г. 2:32 ?

Comment: А какой язык вы собираетесь использовать для преобразования даты? Или вы хотите делать это прямо в БД?

Comment: + имеет смысл указать о какой вообще базе идет речь.

Comment: С помощью PHP..

Comment: Речь идет о Mysql.

Comment: Вы не можете хранить в базе дату в формате "d.m.Y" в поле типа `INT` (это не имеет смысла). Либо вы храните дату как UNIX timestamp в поле типа `INT`, либо как дату в поле `DATE` (`DATETIME`). Вы уж как-то определитесь.

Comment: Вот это руководство поможет вам задавать более качественные вопросы, касающиеся баз данных. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169/181472

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
date('r', $timestamp);
```

где `$timestamp` - это время в секундах с начала эпохи UNIX (т.н. [UNIX timestamp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)).

Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php